# IoC Windsor Castle Unit Testing Business Object

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

We are trying to introduce DI and an IoC container (Castle) into an existing ASP.Net Webforms application. We have a Web Project, a Services Project and a Business Obj Project.

Our intention is to introduce DI and unit testing in the Business Project. The Business project doesn't know about the web project. The Dependency goes from Web > Services > Business. The web project is our root that we will install and register the components.

Once the components are in registered, how, in the Services project do we call Resolve on the container to get the correct Business Object, since the Service Project doesn't know about the Web project?

Comment: You don't call `Resolve` in the services - that is not DI, that is [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

Comment: The consumer of such service should get that service injected. This is a recursive process all the way up to the top of your object graph and you only resolve those root objects.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm starting to understand it. Since this is a mature web app, that would be a significant amount of work to introduce unit testing. Are there other alternatives? What about not using an IoC and just using method injection at the service level?